# Synchronize python files between my development computer and my raspberry

Tags: python, version-control, raspberry-pi

I am writing a web python application with tornado framework on a raspberry pi.

What i actually do is to connect to my raspberry with ssh. I am writing my source code with vi, on the raspberry.

What i want to do is to write source code on my development computer but i do not know how to synchronize (transfer) this source code to raspberry.
It is possible to do that with ftp for example but i will have to do something manual.

I am looking for a system where i can press F5 on my IDE and this IDE will transfer modified source files. Do you know how can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a proper Version Control System? [Github](https://github.com) is a free online revision control storage area. You can then use `git` to push your work to Github, then you can fetch it back onto the Raspberry Pi. You can also mount your project directory from the Pi onto your dev box using `sshfs`, and then you'll be working on the Pi's files directly. This won't provide any form of backup though.

Comment: That is a good idea but i have no internet connexion for this application. Thanks

Comment: BitTorrent sync? Rsync? Edit and test locally (try Docker) then push to your pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some IDEs like [JetBrains PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) are supporting automatically file upload via ssh/scp/ftp.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that SFTP support is a paid feature

Comment: @cricket_007 is absolutely correct, per [feature matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), and I just compared a community edition to one of my licensed versions.

Comment: @stevieb That doesn't stop an `sshfs` file mount, though

Comment: @cricket_007 No. I do this reasonably often from my Pi (albeit I use intelliJ IDEA/IntelliJ CLion as I do my coding in Perl and C), but the premise is the same; the IDE will see the `sshfs` mount as a local directory at that point. I do this so I can run my Pi headless, so it can spend more time compiling/running code instead of managing a GUI.

Comment: @stevieb I'm saying for those who would not want to pay for Ultimate

Answer (score 0):

Following a couple of bad experiences where I lost code which was only on my Pi's SD card, I now run WinSCP on my laptop, and edit files from Pi on my laptop, they open in Notepad++ and WinSCP automatically saves edits to Pi. And also I can use WinSCP folder sync feature to copy contents of SD card folder to my latop. Not perfect, but better what I was doing before

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before using bitbucket as a standard repository and it is not too bad. If you set up cron scripts to git pull it's almost like continuous integration.